# How to read http2 pseudofields

Tags: go, http2

I have an http2 handler and it received http2 requests. Now I need to access :authority pseudoheader field in the request. How to go about it?
I am aware of few options as below:

1. Hijack the http connection -> But I do not want to lose the http layer capabilities, it's really an overkill. All I need is just the value of that pseudo header field.
2. Get the underlying tcp conn without hijacking it and read the frames from it. -> Now, how to do this? One way could be to get the tcp conn in http.Server.ConnState (but there is no guarantee with this I think. I quite often find that the connection is closed and in any case i find it very cumbersome).

Is there a way, to just extract the pseudofield alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Host in http.Request does it in the sense that, it reads the :authority into r.Host field. But other fields are difficult to get a hold of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mapping from `http.Request` fields to http2 pseudo-headers:

```
req.Host       => :authority 
req.Method     => :method 
req.RequestURI => :path        // if :method != "CONNECT"
req.RequestURI => :authority   // if :method == "CONNECT"
```

You can find the relevant code in the source at the following locations: 
https://ref.gotd.dev/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go.html#line-5738
https://ref.gotd.dev/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go.html#line-5803